# node exports return an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

In my app.js I exported the function:

```
var video_sets = [];
...// get the video_sets
console.log(video_sets);
module.exports = {
    requestVideo: function () {
        return video_sets;
    }
};
```

I tried using `console.log(video_sets)` to make sure it's not an empty array.
When I call this function in another module I get an empty object.

```
var app = require('./app');
console.log(app.requestVideo());
```

Comment: Can you explain how you put data into video_sets , provide more code so that we can help @Big_t boy

Comment: Its just a array contains a list of strings

Comment: How you are setting /pushing value into array

Comment: video_sets.push(video[i].src);

Answer (score 0):

You can only do :

```
module.exports.video_sets = video_sets;
```

No need for extra lines.